# How to give several variadic template template arguments to class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, variadic-templates

How should I give template template argument(s) to class S below?

```
#include "tuple"
template<
    class C1,
    template<class... C3> class C2,
    class... C3,
    template<class... C5> class C4,
    class... C5
> struct S {};
int main() {
    S<
        int,
        std::tuple<int, char>,
        std::tuple<double>
    > s;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.8.3 complains:

```
expected a class template, got 'std::tuple<int, char>'
```

What should I use instead of tuple? S has to know C3 in its operator() but I can't give C3 there because boost::mpl::for_each expects a specific signature for operator(). Previously I've handled this by giving `tuple<int, char>()` as a regular argument to deduce the templates but that doesn't seem possible here. A similar question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12782697/1226313 but that seems to only apply to functions not classes. To be clear, inside of operator() of S I'd like to pass C3 (and C5, C7, etc.) as an argument to a variadic function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a template, not a type:

```
S<int, std::tuple, /* std::tuple */> s;
```

Comment: But how do I provide C3 (and C5, C7, ...), i.e. the int and char in `tuple<int,char>`?

Comment: @user1226313: `S<int, std::tuple, int, char>`?

Comment: That doesn't work if I want several packs of variadic template template parameters, i.e. uncomment C4 and C5.

Comment: @user1226313: No. The entire approach is more than questionable. If you want to transmit packs of types, use tuples.

Comment: Am I not (tying to) doing that in the question? I've tried several things and cannot see a way to give more than one set of variadic templates to a class. For functions there's already an answer but not for classes (your answer does work if only one set of variadic templates is sufficient).

Comment: @user1226313: I meant actual tuple types. Like `template <typename ...Tuples> struct S {};`, and then: `S<std::tuple<A, B, C>, std::tuple<int, bool>> s;` Then unpack on the other side.

Comment: I'm having trouble accessing C3 (and C5, etc.) this way to pass to a variadic function, could you provide an example? In the linked answer I can just give Types1()... or Types2()... as an argument to it but how do I get to them if S only sees the tuple and not its content? I edited the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: Not really. Make a new, answerable question that *describes the real problem*. The present question seems useless and unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

The template arguments don't match the template parameters. If this is the primary template:

```
template<
    class C1,
    template<class...> class C2,  // note 1
    class... C3,
    template<class...> class C4,  // note 1
    class... C5
> struct S {};
```

<sup>`// note 1`: I removed the names of the template template parameter parameter packs `C3` and `C5` because they have no purpose.</sup>

Then you would instantiate the template like this:

```
S<
    int,
    std::tuple,
    int, char,
    std::tuple,
    double
>
```

But the above won't work because any parameter pack must be at the end of the parameters list in a primary template declaration.

If you want to be able to instantiate the template like this:

```
S<
    int,
    std::tuple<int, char>,
    std::tuple<double>
>
```

Then you need to realise that `std::tuple<int,char>` and `std::tuple<double>` are not templates. They are classes generated from templates. The following primary template will match those arguments:

```
template<
    class C1,
    class C2,
    class C3
> struct S;
```

If you want to get at the types inside the tuples, there are many ways to do that. The following way may not be the best, but it is the closest to what you originally asked for. You can add a partial specialization after the primary template, to be used when `C2` and `C3` are specializations of `std::tuple`:

```
// Partial specialisation
template<
    class C1,
    class... C3,
    class... C5
> struct S<
    C1,
    std::tuple<C3...>,
    std::tuple<C5...>
> {
    auto operator()() const {
        // do something with C1,C3...,C5... here
    }
};
```