# Why does template argument deduction fail with overloaded function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

I have a template function that should take a function pointer and arguments, then invoke the function pointer with the given arguments (let's call it `Invoke`). However, when I call the template function with an overloaded function as an argument, template deduction fails.

I have used enable_if so that only one overload would be valid, but this didn't help.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

void foo(int, int){}
void foo(std::string, std::string) {}

template <bool Val1, bool Val2, bool ...Rest>
struct And
{
    enum {value = And<Val1 && Val2, Rest...>::value};
};
template <bool Val1, bool Val2>
struct And<Val1, Val2>
{
    enum {value = Val1 && Val2};
};

template <typename ...Params, typename ...Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<
    And<std::is_convertible<Args, Params>::value...>::value
>::type>
void Invoke(void (*fn)(Params...), Args ...args){}

int main() {
    Invoke(&foo, "a", "b");
    return 0;
}
```

Try on [ideone](https://ideone.com/Httn9G).

The compiler complains that `mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding ‘std::is_convertible<Args, Params>::value’`, when both overloads are present.
When I comment out the `int` overload, the program compiles just fine, and when I comment out the `std::string` overload, deduction fails as it should, since `const char[]` is not implicitly convertible to `int`.

The standard (section 17.8.2.1.6.2 of the C++17 standard) says the following:

> If the argument is an overload set (not containing function templates), trial argument deduction is
>   attempted using each of the members of the set. If deduction succeeds for only one of the overload set
>   members, that member is used as the argument value for the deduction. If deduction succeeds for more
>   than one member of the overload set the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.

So I would expect that the compiler would try the `int` overload, where deduction would fail. When it tries the `std::string` overload, the deduction would succeed.

Since the deduction would succeed for only one of the overload set members, I would expect that it would then proceed as if the `int` overload didn't exist, and the compilation would succeed like it does when the other overload is commented out, but it fails.

Where am I wrong?

References to standard will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with vardic templates, but `typename ...Params, typename ...Args,` seems off. How do you expect the compiler to differentiate between the two? But again, not too familiar with vardic templates, so maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Two parameter packs can be used if they are in deduced contexts. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template

Comment: Why not just define `template <bool... Args>
struct And :std::bool_constant<(Args && ...)> {};`?

Comment: @L.F. Because I don't have C++17. Also, if I did, I would probably just not define `struct And` at all, and just use the fold expression directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that there is more than one function that works.  The deduction of `Params...` is going to happen before you even get to the SFINAE part of the template.  When it tries to deduce `Params..` from `void (*fn)(Params...)` it matches `void foo(int, int)` and `void foo(std::string, std::string)`.  Since it finds multiple matches, 17.8.2.1.6.2 states that it is treated as a non deduced context.

Since it cant deduce a type, you get hard stop error.  SFINAE only happens after the template parameter deduction step, which it can't get to in this case.

Comment: Oh, now that I look at it, SFINAE happens during overload resolution, which happens after template argument deduction. That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Tomeamis Not exactly.  The compiler tries to deduce `Params...`, it can't, so it leave it as non deduced.  Then it deduces `Args...`, gets that on moves on to the last parameter.  Once it gets there you get a hard error because `Params...` wasn't deduced, and you need it to be to try and apply SFINAE.

Answer (score 5):

The `&foo` is not a function pointer, but an overload set. You have to be explicit:

```
Invoke(static_cast<void(*)(std::string, std::string)>(&foo), "a", "b");
```

To simplify the failing `enable_if`, you could take an unspecified function pointer type, with a variadic arugment pack, and check `is_invocable`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable

Comment: That's why I put the standard quotation about overload sets in the question. Could you elaborate why it doesn't apply here?
Thanks for is_invocable, though, I didn't know about that.