# Applying CTAD with multiple template parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Following some of the solutions provided here [How can I have multiple parameter packs in a variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template), I'm hoping to apply multiple parameter packs to a classes and use CTAD to make the class more usable.

Here is what I came up with (on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35c56f0e5a97b6a0)), but this gives:

> error: class template argument deduction failed

Here is the code I tried:

```
// A template to hold a parameter pack
template < typename... >
struct Typelist {};

// Declaration of a template
template< typename TypeListOne 
        , typename TypeListTwo
        > 
struct Foo;     

// A template to hold a parameter pack
template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
struct Foo< Typelist < Args1... >
                 , Typelist < Args2... >
                 >{
    template <typename... Args>
    struct Bar1{
        Bar1(Args... myArgs) {
            _t = std::make_tuple(myArgs...);
        }
        std::tuple<Args...> _t;
    };

    template <typename... Args>
    struct Bar2{
        Bar2(Args... myArgs) {
            _t = std::make_tuple(myArgs...);
        }
        std::tuple<Args...> _t;
    };

    Bar1<Args1...> _b1;
    Bar2<Args2...> _b2;

    Foo(Bar1<Args1...>& b1, Bar2<Args2...>& b2) {
        _b1 = b1;
        _b2 = b2;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Foo{Foo::Bar1(1, 2.0, 3), Foo::Bar2(100, 23.4, 45)};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO there's no way for the compiler, even with deduction guide, to understand `Foo::Bar1(1, 2.0, 3)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, CTAD is not done when using the scope resolution operator, so `Foo::` can never be used. You must specify the template arguments for this `Foo` explicitly.

I suggest you simply move `Bar1` and `Bar2` outside the `Foo` partial specialization into the namespace scope and use

```
Foo{Bar1(1, 2.0, 3), Bar2(100, 23.4, 45)};
```

instead.

---

Then you will get an error that deduction for `Foo` fails. This is because only constructors in the *primary* template are considered for implicit deduction guides. But the constructor that you want to use is in the partial specialization, not the primary template.

So you will need to add an appropriate deduction guide yourself, e.g.:

```
template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
Foo(Bar1<Args1...>, Bar2<Args2...>) -> Foo<Typelist<Args1...>, Typelist<Args2...>>;
```

---

Then you will get an error that no constructor is viable. This is because you are taking `Bar1<Args1...>& b1` and `Bar2<Args2...>& b2` as non-`const` lvalue references, but you provide prvalues for them. Non-`const` lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues and so you get an error. Either take the parameters by-value or by `const` lvalue reference.

---

Finally you will get an error that `_b1` and `_b2` do not have default constructors, which is true. They are needed because you are default-initializing `_b1` and `_b2` in your constructor. You only later assign them values.

So either add default constructors to `Bar1` and `Bar2` or better use initialization instead of assignment:

```
Foo(const Bar1<Args1...>& b1, const Bar2<Args2...>& b2) : _b1(b1), _b2(b2) { }
```

---

After all these steps the code should compile. I am not sure what *exactly* your goal is, so not entirely sure whether this will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks here is a working implementation incorporating your answer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f02a58966e185b