# How to differentiate / separate two consecutive variadic template parameter pack of template function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

```
template<class... Ts, class... Ps>
void Fun(Ts... ts, Ps... ps){};

Fun(1,'a',"blah", 2.13, 3.14f); 
// how do we separate which part is for ts or ps params pack
```

is there a way to explicit annotate which part of params is belongs to ts/ps variadic params?

Comment: You need a helper class to deliniate the packs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template) for an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have multiple parameter packs in a variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template)

Answer (score 0):

No, variadic template packs are greedy and you can not put them next to each other.

You could wrap your packs in tuples and pass them that way.

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... Ts, class... Ps>
void Fun(std::tuple<Ts...> ts, std::tuple<Ps...> ps) {
    // Do something with the tuples
}

int main()
{
   Fun(std::make_tuple(1,'a',"blah"), std::make_tuple(2.13, 3.14f)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do we separate which part is for ts or ps params pack

More straightforward would be to rewrite the function to take 2 tuples.

But notice that you can already split both parameter packs.

`Ts` is non deducible, and `Ps` takes so all the remaining for deduction,
so by explicitly give `Ts` arguments, you split them:

```
Fun(1, 'a', "blah", 2.13, 3.14f);            // Ts: []; Ps: [int, char, const char*, double, float]
Fun<int, char>(1, 'a', "blah", 2.13, 3.14f); // Ts: [int, char]; Ps: [const char*, double, float]
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54103e26710b474d)