# Generalizing std::conditional_t<>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a function that computes a certain object from a given parameter (say, an important node from a graph). Now, when calculating such an object, the function might allocate some memory. Sometimes I want the function to just return the result, and sometimes to return the result plus the memory used to compute it.

I typically solve this binary case like this:

```
enum class what {
    what1,  // return, e.g., just an int
    what2   // return, e.g., a std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>
};

template <what w>
std::conditional_t<w == what::what1, int, std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>>
calculate_something(const param& p) { ... }
```

I would like to generalize the solution above to longer enumerations

```
enum class list_whats {
    what1,
    what2,
    what3,
    what4,
    what5
};
```

One possible solution is to nest as many `std::conditional_t` as needed

```
template <list_whats what>
std::conditional_t<
    what == list_whats::what1,
    int,
    std::conditional_t<
        what == list_whats::what2,
        float,
        ....
    >
>
>
calculate_something(const param& p) { ... }
```

But this is cumbersome and perhaps not too elegant.

Does anyone know how to do this in C++ 17?

**EDIT**

To make the question perfectly clear: how do I implement the function `return_something` so as to be able to run the following main?

```
int main() {
    int s1 = return_something<list_whats::what1>();
    s1 = 3;

    float s2 = return_something<list_whats::what2>();
    s2 = 4.0f;

    double s3 = return_something<list_whats::what3>();
    s3 = 9.0;

    std::string s4 = return_something<list_whats::what4>();
    s4 = "qwer";

    std::vector<int> s5 = return_something<list_whats::what5>();
    s5[3] = 25;
}
```

Comment: The complexity does not end in the return type. The body of the function must also be adjusted to produce the conditional result. Do you have a plan for that? A cascade of `if constexpr`?

Comment: You only need to specify the return type in a declaration that isn't the definition. In your example `template <list_whats what> auto calculate_something` would be fine

Comment: @j6t, I added a proposal of a solution below.

Comment: @Caleth, doesn't work, see example of main [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73730003/12075306)

Comment: @llualpu You need to return the right type in the body, but then [it's fine](https://godbolt.org/z/K1659fvxc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should use `std::conditional` at all to solve your problem. If I get this right, you want to use a template parameter to tell your function what to return. The *elegant* way to do this could look something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

enum class what { what1, what2 };

template <what W>
auto compute() {
  if constexpr (W == what::what1) {
    return 100;
  }
  if constexpr (W == what::what2) {
    return std::pair{100, std::vector<int>{}};
  }
}

auto main() -> int {
  [[maybe_unused]] const auto as_int = compute<what::what1>();
  [[maybe_unused]] const auto as_pair = compute<what::what2>();
}
```

You can also use template specialization if you prefer another syntax:

```cpp
template <what W>
auto compute();

template <>
auto compute<what::what1>() {
  return 100;
}

template <>
auto compute<what::what2>() {
  return std::pair{100, std::vector<int>{}};
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer so far. This didn't work for me when I first tried it because a statement like `return {1,2,3,4,5};` doesn't work with `auto`. I should've done `return std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5};`. Now, with just `auto`, although I have to write the type of the returned value before the value (like with the vector), everything will turn out to be more readable, I think. Thanks!

Comment: @llualpu that's because the expression `{1,2,3,4,5}` *doesn't have a type*

Comment: I've accepted your answer given its simplicity.

Comment: Also (trying to be constructive), I don't think that template specialization is a good idea. _In my context_, I can guarantee that the code in every specialization will be very similar, and would involve repeating (potentially) lots of code. [Example](https://github.com/LAL-project/linear-arrangement-library/blob/master/lal/detail/properties/tree_centroid.hpp#L116)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

- `what_pair` is a pair that corresponds one enum to one type.
- `what_type_index` accepts a enum and a `std::tuple<what_pair<...>...>` and searches the tuple map where the enums are equal and returns `index`. It returns maximum `std::size_t` value, if no match was found.
- `what_type` is the final type, it is the tuple element at the found position. The program won't compile when the index is `std::size_t` max value because of invalid `std::tuple` access.

```
template<what W, typename T>
struct what_pair {
    constexpr static what w = W;
    using type = T;
};

template<what w, typename tuple_map>
constexpr auto what_type_index() {
    std::size_t index = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
    auto search_map = [&]<std::size_t... Ints>(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        ((std::tuple_element_t<Ints, tuple_map>::w == w ? (index = Ints) : 0), ...);
    };
    search_map(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<tuple_map>>());
    return index;
}

template<what w, typename tuple_map>
using what_type = typename 
    std::tuple_element_t<what_type_index<w, tuple_map>(), tuple_map>::type;
```

and this is the example usage:

```
int main() {
    using what_map = std::tuple<
        what_pair<what::what1, int>,
        what_pair<what::what2, float>,
        what_pair<what::what3, double>,
        what_pair<what::what4, std::string>,
        what_pair<what::what5, std::vector<int>>>;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<what_type<what::what1, what_map>, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<what_type<what::what2, what_map>, float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<what_type<what::what3, what_map>, double>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<what_type<what::what4, what_map>, std::string>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<what_type<what::what5, what_map>, std::vector<int>>);

    //compilation error, because 'what6' wasn't specified in the 'what_map'
    using error = what_type<what::what6, what_map>;
}
```

---

[try it out on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j3zoodcf5).

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution that nests two structs: the first takes a list of Boolean values to indicate which type should be used, and the nested struct takes the list of possible types (see `conditional_list` in the example code below -- the nested structs were [inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63348353/12075306)). But perhaps it's not elegant enough. I'm wondering if there is a possible solution of the form

```
std::conditional_list<
    ..., // list of Boolean values, (of any length!)
    ... // list of types           (list that should be as long as the first)
>::type
```

---

**My proposal**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<auto A, auto... ARGS>
constexpr auto sum = A + sum<ARGS...>;
template<auto A>
constexpr auto sum<A> = A;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <bool... values>
static constexpr bool exactly_one_v = sum<values...> == 1;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <bool... values>
struct which {
    static_assert(exactly_one_v<values...>);

    template <std::size_t idx, bool v1, bool... vs>
    struct _which_impl {
        static constexpr std::size_t value =
            (v1 ? idx : _which_impl<idx + 1, vs...>::value);
    };

    template <std::size_t idx, bool v>
    struct _which_impl<idx, v> {
        static constexpr std::size_t value = (v ? idx : idx + 1);
    };

    static constexpr std::size_t value = _which_impl<0, values...>::value;
};

template <bool... conds>
static constexpr std::size_t which_v = which<conds...>::value;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <std::size_t ith_idx, typename... Ts>
struct ith_type {
    template <std::size_t cur_idx, typename t1, typename... ts>
    struct _ith_type_impl {
        typedef
            std::conditional_t<
                ith_idx == cur_idx,
                t1,
                typename _ith_type_impl<cur_idx + 1, ts...>::type
            >
            type;
    };

    template <std::size_t cur_idx, typename t1>
    struct _ith_type_impl<cur_idx, t1> {
        typedef
            std::conditional_t<ith_idx == cur_idx, t1, std::nullptr_t>
            type;
    };

    static_assert(ith_idx < sizeof...(Ts));
    typedef typename _ith_type_impl<0, Ts...>::type type;
};

template <std::size_t ith_idx, typename... ts>
using ith_type_t = typename ith_type<ith_idx, ts...>::type;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <bool... conds>
struct conditional_list {
    template <typename... ts>
    struct good_type {
        static_assert(sizeof...(conds) == sizeof...(ts));
        typedef ith_type_t<which_v<conds...>, ts...> type;
    };
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

enum class list_whats {
    what1,
    what2,
    what3,
    what4,
    what5,
};

template <list_whats what>
typename conditional_list<
    what == list_whats::what1,
    what == list_whats::what2,
    what == list_whats::what3,
    what == list_whats::what4,
    what == list_whats::what5
>::template good_type<
    int,
    float,
    double,
    std::string,
    std::vector<int>
>::type
return_something() noexcept {
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what1) { return 1; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what2) { return 2.0f; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what3) { return 3.0; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what4) { return "42"; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what5) { return {1,2,3,4,5}; }
}

int main() {
    auto s1 = return_something<list_whats::what1>();
    s1 = 3;

    auto s2 = return_something<list_whats::what2>();
    s2 = 4.0f;

    auto s3 = return_something<list_whats::what3>();
    s3 = 9.0;

    auto s4 = return_something<list_whats::what4>();
    s4 = "qwer";

    auto s5 = return_something<list_whats::what5>();
    s5[3] = 25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to working only with types is to write a function that returns the specific type, or an `identity<type>`. It's sometimes more readable. Here is an example:

```
    // if you don't have it in std
    template<typename T>
    struct identity {
        using type = T;
    };
     
    enum class what {
        what1,
        what2,
        what3
    };
     
    template<what w>
    auto return_type_for_calc() {
        if constexpr (w == what::what1) {
            return identity<int>();
        } else if constexpr (w==what::what2) {
            return identity<double>();
        } else {
            return identity<float>();
        }
    }
     
    template<what w>
    decltype(return_type_for_calc<w>())
    calculate_something()
    {
        return {};
    }
     
    int main() {
        calculate_something<what::what1>();
        calculate_something<what::what2>();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. When I implement `calculate_something` with, say `if constexpr (w == what::what1) { return 1; }` I get a compiler error: "no viable conversion from 'int' to [..] (aka 'identity<int>')". It seems that I would have to implement 'identity<>' for every instance of `what` or something, I don't know.

Comment: @Ilualpu Don't return `1`. If you mean `int`, return `identity<int>()`; You don't need to implement it for anything specially - the generic case works. See https://onlinegdb.com/xYPMzM8qZ

Comment: @Ilualpu note that we have 2 functions - one to deduce return type (with `if constexpr`) and one to calculate the value (`calculate_something()`)

Comment: The function `calculate_something` has to return a value, not a type. I've edited the question to make this clearer. Also, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732987/12075306) for further clarification. I'm sorry I haven't been clear enough from the start.

Comment: I also proposed a solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73730003/12075306) which should have helped you in understanding my question better. But I guess everything was too obfuscated.

Comment: @Ilualpu Look at my answer again. `calculate_something()` returns a value. The _type of value_ that it returns depends on another, type-deducing function.

Answer (score 0):

Although I already posted an answer to my own question, and I accepted an answer from another user, I thought I could post another possibility in tackling this problem using the following struct

```
template <typename... Ts> struct type_sequence { };
```

which I learnt about in [this talk by Andrei Alexandrescu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va9I2qivBOA). Since I learnt quite a bit by using it and the result is a bit simpler than [the original answer that used two nested structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73730003/12075306) I thought I would share it here. However, the solution I would actually implement is [the one that was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732987/12075306).

This is the full code with a `main` function included. Notice the change in the specification of function `return_something`. Now this function indicates the return type (which I like very much, perhaps I'm old fashioned) in a more readable way than in my first answer. You can [try it out here](https://godbolt.org/z/8ojvKTK1n).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <bool... values>
struct which {
    template <std::size_t idx, bool v1, bool... vs>
    struct _which_impl {
        static constexpr std::size_t value =
            (v1 ? idx : _which_impl<idx + 1, vs...>::value);
    };

    template <std::size_t idx, bool v>
    struct _which_impl<idx, v> {
        static constexpr std::size_t value = (v ? idx : idx + 1);
    };

    static constexpr std::size_t value = _which_impl<0, values...>::value;
};

template <std::size_t ith_idx, typename... Ts>
struct ith_type {
    template <std::size_t cur_idx, typename t1, typename... ts>
    struct _ith_type_impl {
        using type =
            std::conditional_t<
                ith_idx == cur_idx,
                t1,
                typename _ith_type_impl<cur_idx + 1, ts...>::type
            >;
    };

    template <std::size_t cur_idx, typename t1>
    struct _ith_type_impl<cur_idx, t1> {
        using type = std::conditional_t<ith_idx == cur_idx, t1, std::nullptr_t>;
    };

    using type = typename _ith_type_impl<0, Ts...>::type;
};

template <std::size_t ith_idx, typename... ts>
using ith_type_t = typename ith_type<ith_idx, ts...>::type;

template <bool... conds>
static constexpr std::size_t which_v = which<conds...>::value;

template <typename... Ts> struct type_sequence { };

template <bool... values> struct bool_sequence {
    static constexpr std::size_t which = which_v<values...>;
};

template <std::size_t ith_idx, typename... Ts>
struct ith_type<ith_idx, type_sequence<Ts...>> : ith_type<ith_idx, Ts...>
{ };

template <typename bool_sequence, typename type_sequence>
struct conditional_list {
    using type = ith_type_t<bool_sequence::which, type_sequence>;
};

template <typename bool_sequence, typename type_sequence>
using conditional_list_t =
    typename conditional_list<bool_sequence, type_sequence>::type;

enum class list_whats {
    what1,
    what2,
    what3,
    what4,
    what5,
};

template <list_whats what>
conditional_list_t<
    bool_sequence<
        what == list_whats::what1,
        what == list_whats::what2,
        what == list_whats::what3,
        what == list_whats::what4,
        what == list_whats::what5
    >,
    type_sequence<
        int,
        float,
        double,
        std::string,
        std::vector<int>
    >
>
return_something() noexcept {
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what1) { return 1; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what2) { return 2.0f; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what3) { return 3.0; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what4) { return "42"; }
    if constexpr (what == list_whats::what5) { return {1,2,3,4,5}; }
}

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] auto s1 = return_something<list_whats::what1>();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto s2 = return_something<list_whats::what2>();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto s3 = return_something<list_whats::what3>();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto s4 = return_something<list_whats::what4>();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto s5 = return_something<list_whats::what5>();
}
```